# Changing current working directory (cwd) to current file directory in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, working-directory

So I'm trying to change the directory the integrated terminal runs my Python scripts in from the root workspace (the default, I guess) to the running file directory. I want to do this as I'm more used to work with paths relative to running file than to root dir. Also sometimes I use quite large directory trees and even paths to near directory files get quite long by starting them from root dir. This would also allow me to use Path Intellisense extension as it seems to base suggestions on the current file dir.
I heard about changing the lauch.json file but I'm looking for a definitive solution that avoids having to change this in all projects.

I have already tried to change `settings.json` cwd option to `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}"` but it doesn´t seem to take any effect, even after reloading.

I'm not sure what other infos are relevant here, but nevertheless i'm running vscode on windows 11 version 21H2. Any other info feel free to ask.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: create a global launch configuration